# Integrating ffmpeg in xcode5, Cannot find gcc

Tags: ios, ios7, ffmpeg, xcode5, llvm-gcc

I have been trying to integrate ffmpeg in xcode5.
The step [here][1]

[1]: [FFMPEG integration on iphone/ ipad project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854190/ffmpeg-integration-on-iphone-ipad-project/15429359#15429359) says that cc parameter needs to be gcc in iphoneOs.platform.

But I could not find it in my xcode5.
It is present in xcode 4.6.3 that I have.

I tried the ./configure command with cc as gcc from xcode4.
Something like this :

```
./configure --prefix=armv7 --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-    ffserver --enable-avresample --enable-cross-compile --   sysroot="/Applications/Xcode5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk" --target-os=darwin --cc="/Applications/Xcode4.6.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc" --extra-cflags="-arch armv7 -mfpu=neon -miphoneos-version-min=6.0" --extra-ldflags="-arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=6.0" --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a9 --enable-pic
```

It works ok but then the make command after fails like this:

```
libavcodec/arm/mdct_vfp.S:113:unknown register alias 'TCOS_D0_HEAD'
libavcodec/arm/mdct_vfp.S:114:unknown register alias 'TCOS_D1_HEAD'
libavcodec/arm/mdct_vfp.S:115:unknown register alias 'TCOS_S0_TAIL'
make: *** [libavcodec/arm/mdct_vfp.o] Error 1
```

What am I doing wrong here?? Where can I find gcc for xcode5??