# Cannot use FFmpeg in Xcode iOS Project (file .h not found)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ffmpeg, libavformat

I followed almost step by step [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854190/ffmpeg-integration-on-iphone-ipad-project).

Almost because I downloaded, as a user suggested, [ffmpeg ios library already built from here](https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ffmpeg-ios/ffmpeg-ios-master.tar.bz2)

I followed from "**Linking static libraries in Xcode**" but I cannot import anyway the header files of ffmpeg. (So I got the .a files)

For example

```
#include "avformat.h"
// or
#import "libavformat/avformat.h"
// or
#import <libavformat/avformat.h>
```

Everything that I use does not work.

I specify that those .a files are currently in my project directory, indeed, if I import the .a file, it doesn't complain that it isn't found, but when compiling, it complains about UTF-8 stuff because .a files are object libraries and cannot be imported that way.

I put also the Header Search Paths for the project as it was suggested and the config.log file but nothing.

Also I see libraries are missing from every project example of FFmpeg I was able to find on GitHub.

Any ideas?