# How to use run ffmpeg command in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ffmpeg, xcode7

I had successfully build  ffmpeg into xcode but I didn't get idea , how to execute command into project.I research hard on it and fined how to play video using encoding and decoding,but did not get idea how to run command.

Comment: You can't run external programs from an iOS app, not even if it's bundled together with the app.  It may be possible if you're jailbreaking.  If you want to use it as a library, you will have to find an external reference or tutorial.

Comment: i have already added ffmpeg library into xocde from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15429359/3384769) refrence

Comment: OR any other way to use ffmpeg functionality ?

Comment: Please explain exactly what the problem you are having is.  If it's just a matter of not knowing how to use the library, that is off-topic, and your question will be closed.

Comment: i have done video playing using library but how can i applying overlay and filter effects using library? i have already read ffmpeg documentation but not getting idea for filter and overlay using library.

Comment: I guess you have to code against libav* to do this. Overlay filter is not a difficult one to program. Check the `filtering_video.c` example.

Comment: how can I use this .c file into project and its method, I added it into project and successfully compiled.@halfelf

Comment: @pramod did you got any solution for overlaying the video with another video using ffmpeg in ios...?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run ffmpeg command directly via code, instead you should leverage the c code to do encoding decoding which can be achieved by using objective c wrappers. [FFmpegWrapper](https://github.com/OpenWatch/FFmpegWrapper) gives you a lightweight wrapper class for media conversion.